# How can I triage slow userspace boot time?

Tags: systemd, boot

I am experiencing extremely slow *userspace* load time compared to the *kernel* loading time, as it can be seen in this `systemd-analyze`:

```
jnavarro@almanzora:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 14.134s (kernel) + 1min 30.675s (userspace) = 1min 44.809s 
graphical.target reached after 12.124s in userspace
```

When I also asks the `systemd-analyze blame` I do not see any "good candidate":

```
jnavarro@almanzora:~$ systemd-analyze blame
          7.387s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.863s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.996s docker.service
          1.966s exim4.service
          1.895s systemd-cryptsetup@luks\foo\bar\zaz\.service
          1.256s fwupd.service
          1.061s upower.service
          1.008s alsa-restore.service
           978ms dev-mapper-almanzora\foo\bar\zaz.device
           756ms udisks2.service
```

Any idea where I can find what is slowing down my boot time?  Seems like `systemd` cannot help me anymore.

--EDIT--

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` output:

```
jnavarro@almanzora:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @12.124s
└─multi-user.target @12.124s
  └─docker.service @10.127s +1.996s
    └─network-online.target @10.125s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2.737s +7.387s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.416s +319ms
          └─dbus.service @2.413s
            └─basic.target @2.392s
              └─sockets.target @2.392s
                └─docker.socket @2.390s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2.387s
                    └─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount @22.662s +9ms
                      └─systemd-modules-load.service @548ms +95ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @531ms
                          └─-.mount @526ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @531ms
                              └─...
```

Comment: Try with comand `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and post its output

Comment: please post it (just click on *edit*) in your OP, not here

Comment: See #3 in this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot But if other services need network it may delay them.

Answer (score 1):

If `systemd-analyze blame` does not identify the delaying application/service this may mean that something else other than systemd is causing the delay.

- This could be caused by a device... Try to remove all unplug-gable devices (usb etc.) and reboot, a firmware/driver could cause the delay
- You could login as tty2 after boot (ctrl+alt+f2) to avoid loading the desktop and its applications, then from there use ps to see what's running and what took time to execute.

`ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd` will list started tasks with the time/date they were started and with `ps -aux` you could check the used cpu time per process.

- Also a defective hardware (like hard drive) may cause delay as well, you can check with a live cd, or by booting a different kernel version, or a different distribution then check if it's impacted as well

Comment: I am afraid nothing relevant can be seen in any of the `ps` command invocations.  Boot time is however improved when I "simply boot the laptop" without having it connected to its docking station, so it might be the cause.

Is there any clear way of knowing which _usb_ device is taking so long to boot?

The laptop is a Thinkpad and the docking station is an "official" _usb3_ one and it does not have any slow device attached to itself.

Comment: @Navarro here is some details about kernel modules (drivers)... https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module ... you may try to boot device by device, or unload/load related kernel modules manually and check if any one is requiring more time...

Comment: But that would speed up the kernel boot time, which is quite low already compared to the userspace loading time.  In fact, the kernel takes only ~14s while the userspace took around ~1m30s.  There is no way of checking what composes that "userland"?